# Remove 1-3 length character from string in sql

Tags: string, oracle

From a space delimited string, i would like to **remove all words that are long from 1 to 3 characters**.

For example: this string

```
LCCPIT A2 LCCMAD B JBPM_JIT CCC
```

should become

```
LCCPIT LCCMAD JBPM_JIT
```

So, A2, B and CCC words are removed (since they are long 2, 1 and 3 characters). Is there a way to do it? I think i could use `REGEXP_REPLACE`, but i didn't find the correct regular expression to have this result.

Answer (score 1):

Split string to words and aggregate back only these substrings whose length is greater than 3.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'LCCPIT A2 LCCMAD B JBPM_JIT CCC' from dual)
```

Query begins here:

```
  3  select listagg(val, ' ') within group (order by lvl) result
  4  from (select regexp_substr(col, '[^ ]+', 1, level) val,
  5               level lvl
  6        from test
  7        connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ' ') + 1
  8       )
  9  where length(val) > 3;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LCCPIT LCCMAD JBPM_JIT

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer a regex replacement trick:

```sql
SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(val, '(^|\s+)\w{1,3}(\s+|$)', ' '))
FROM dual;

-- output is 'LCCPIT LCCMAD JBPM_JIT'
```

### Demo

The strategy above is match any 1, 2, or 3 letter word, along with any surrounding whitespace, and to replace with just a single space.  The outer call to `TRIM()` is necessary to remove dangling spaces which might arise from the first or last word being removed.

Comment: Or, possibly, `\S+` instead of `\w+` to treat all characters that are not separators as words